# Blank screen in Android build with Intel XDK

Tags: android, html, apk, intel-xdk

I created my very first app with Intel XDK, just a "Hello World" is displayed on the screen. The emulator works OK, App Preview works OK, but when I build my Android apk and send it to the device I just obtain a blank screen after the splash screen,

I've tried using "Lean" Code Base instead of "Gold" for the build as [suggested](https://forums.html5dev-software.intel.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=5951), but with the same result, 
This is my `index.html` (the only file I have):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--HTML5 doctype-->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your New Application</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Prevent copy paste for all elements except text fields */
        *  { -webkit-user-select:none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); }
        input, textarea  { -webkit-user-select:text; }
        body { background-color:white; color:black }
    </style>
    <script src='intelxdk.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* Intel native bridge is available */
        var onDeviceReady=function(){
        //hide splash screen
        intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();
        };
        document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",onDeviceReady,false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- content goes here-->
    <h1>Probando...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbloadpqhzgyh4w/pruebaAndroid.Android.4.2.20140507223906.apk) is my apk to download, any idea? Thanks

**UPDATE:** My Intel XDK build is 0876

**UPDATE 2:** Oddly the same started to happen with Intel App Preview, when now I open it I can see the splash screen and then blank.. I tried erasing data and cache, uninstalling and reinstalling but with no luck. It seems to me that some common dependency is broken..

**UPDATE 3:** I tried generating the build without the `<script type="text/javascript">/* Intel native bridge is available */</script>` section int [this APK](https://am-xdk2.s3.amazonaws.com/cust.6cc895c2-be5e-4db8-ba71-a9317f5561f6/app.d4f97019-8679-4e70-a0f0-1ce74e958f61/ANDROID/pruebaAndroid.Android.4.2.20140509195028.apk) and same result. Then removed `<script src='intelxdk.js'></script>` with [this APK](https://am-xdk2.s3.amazonaws.com/cust.6cc895c2-be5e-4db8-ba71-a9317f5561f6/app.d4f97019-8679-4e70-a0f0-1ce74e958f61/ANDROID/pruebaAndroid.Android.4.2.20140509195558.apk) and same result..

**UPDATE 4:** When I try to debug the app with Intel XDK the app is pushed to my device and popups an alert to download an update for Crosswalk. It then downloads 52 MB and shows a message "Failed to update. Try again.".

Comment: Your apk worked fine on my Nexus5 Android-4.4.2, let me know which device and android version you are testing on?

Comment: Ohh, I'm using an LG L9 P778g with Android-4.1.2

Comment: Works fine on a XOLO X900 with Android 4.0.4.

Comment: Just tried it on a Dell Venue 8 3830 with Android 4.3 and it works there.

Comment: Please try these two experiments in this order: 1) remove the `<script> /* Intel native bridge is available */ ... </script>` section of the app. 2) also remove the `<script src='intelxdk.js'></script>` section. I know this is not what you would normally do, but it would help to determine if there is something in the XDK init code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles also try building "Crosswalk for Android" and install, this should work since it adds a runtime in app.

Comment: I updated my question with new info, thanks for your help

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles, please try the experiments I suggested in the prior comment and report on the results.

Comment: @xmnboy I updated my question with the results

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles, this is very odd. How much memory do you have in the device? Is your storage space full? I've heard of some people having issues where their phone is "full" and there is no spare space. If you download Elixir 2 and view the Information tab it provides a lot of useful information regarding storage and RAM usage.

Also, have you tried building the app using the Crosswalk for Android build? This substitutes an alternate webview that provides more consistent behavior across the various versions of Android (it only works on Android 4.x devices).

Comment: It seems the problem resides in the App Crosswalk component as shown in my update, how can I uninstall it? It won't show up in the Applications list..

Answer (score 2):

It is due to some reasons ,either your app did not download properly on your device or the API is blocked due to Cross domain access,  just add `<script src="xhr.js"></script>` after your `intelxdk.js` script inclusion. It will then work on device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just in case someone has a similar problem, this is how I dealt with it.

1. Ensure yo have a very good internet connection, if the connection is poor, most likely the intel XDK will have problems uploading or downloading your app completely.
2. You can opt to download your built app from your ITEL registered email - they always mail you a link to your built app - instead of downloading it via the XDK.
3. Try deleting previous app build in your ITEL XDK server, go to https://appcenter.html5tools-software.intel.com/csd/ControlPanel.aspx to see a list of your upload ITEL XDK app. After deleting do a fresh build.
4. Am not sure about this, but avoid editing your source code as the Intel XDK is uploading your app.

Cheers, enjoy your coding ;)